# How to open facebook account from my app?

Tags: android, facebook

In my app there are 2 edit text, one for username and other for password, and there are 2 buttons. first button is to login to my app and other one is to login in to facebook account, using username and password given  and if both are correct then it should directly start facebook account. How can I do this???

Comment: After starting facebook account what you want to implement? or just want to implement facebook authorization process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u will get answer from API FBDailog.java class..

Comment: can you give me any link please